# sql query treating a int as a string - issues?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

If i do a query like this

```
SELECT * from Foo where Bar = '42'
```

and Bar is a int column. Will that string value be optimized to 42 in the db engine? Will it have some kind of impact if i leave it as it is instead of changing it to:

```
Select * from Foo where Bar = 42
```

This is done on a SQL Compact database if that makes a difference.
I know its not the correct way to do it but it's a big pain going though all code looking at every query and DB schema to see if the column is a int type or not.

Comment: In most sql servers it will be automatically translated to int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*SQL Server* automatically convert it to `INT` that because `INT` has [higher precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309) than `VARCHAR`.

> You should also be aware of the impact that implicit conversions can
>   have on a query’s performance. To demonstrate what I mean, I’ve created and populated the following table in the AdventureWorks2008 database:

```
USE AdventureWorks2008;

IF OBJECT_ID ('ProductInfo', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ProductInfo;

CREATE TABLE ProductInfo
(
  ProductID NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ProductName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ProductInfo
SELECT ProductID, Name
FROM Production.Product;
```

> As you can see, the table includes a primary key configured with the
>   NVARCHAR data type. Because the ProductID column is the primary key,
>   it will automatically be configured with a clustered index. Next, I
>   set the statistics IO to on so I can view information about disk
>   activity:

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON;
```

> Then I run the following SELECT statement to retrieve product
>   information for product 350:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName
FROM ProductInfo
WHERE ProductID = 350;
```

> Because statistics IO is turned on, my results include the following
>   information:
>
> Table 'ProductInfo'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0,
>   read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob
>   read-ahead reads 0.
>
> Two important items to notice is that the query performed a scan and
>   that it took six logical reads to retrieve the data. Because my WHERE
>   clause specified a value in the primary key column as part of the
>   search condition, I would have expected an index seek to be performed,
>   rather than I scan. As the figure below confirms, the database engine performed a scan, rather than a seek. Figure below shows the details of that scan (accessed by hovering the mouse over the scan icon).

[image: convertion]

> Notice that in the Predicate section, the CONVERT_IMPLICIT function is
>   being used to convert the values in the ProductID column in order to
>   compare them to the value of 350 (represented by @1) I passed into the
>   WHERE clause. The reason that the data is being implicitly converted
>   is because I passed the 350 in as an integer value, not a string
>   value, so SQL Server is converting all the ProductID values to
>   integers in order to perform the comparisons.
>
> Because there are relatively few rows in the ProductInfo table,
>   performance is not much of a consideration in this instance. But if
>   your table contains millions of rows, you’re talking about a serious
>   hit on performance. The way to get around this, of course, is to pass
>   in the 350 argument as a string, as I’ve done in the following
>   example:

```
SELECT ProductID, ProductName
FROM ProductInfo
WHERE ProductID = '350';
```

> Once again, the statement returns the product information and the statistics IO data, as shown in the following results:
>
> Now the index is being properly used to locate the record. And if you
>   refer to Figure below, you’ll see that the values in the ProductID
>   column are no longer being implicitly converted before being compared
>   to the 350 specified in the search condition.

[image]

> As this example demonstrates, you need to be aware of how performance
>   can be affected by implicit conversions, just like you need to be
>   aware of any types of implicit conversions being conducted by the
>   database engine. For that reason, you’ll often want to explicitly
>   convert your data so you can control the impact of that conversion.

You can read more about [Data Conversion in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/data-conversion-in-sql-server/).

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the [MSDN chart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) which tells about the implicit conversion you will find that string is implicitly converted into int.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

both should work in your case but the norme is to use quote anyway.
cuz if this work.

Select * from Foo where Bar = 42

this not

Select * from Foo where Bar = %42%

and this will

SELECT * from Foo where Bar = '%42%'

ps: you should anyway look at entity framework and linq query it make it simple...

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken, the SQL Server will read it as `INT` if the string will only contains number (numeric) and you're comparing it to the `INTEGER` column datatype, but if the string is is alphanumeric , then that is the time you will encounter an error or have an unexpected result.

My suggestion is , in `WHERE` clause, if you are comparing `integer`, do not put single quote. that is the best practice to avoid error and unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use always parameters when executing sql by code, to avoid security lacks (EJ: Sql injection).